# VSCode only renders JSDoc link to another file when symbol is imported

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm trying to use JSDoc `@link` annotation to refer to a class on a different file but VSCode doesn't recognize it and the tooltip is rendered as plain text.

I've found a workaround which is to import the symbol into my file. However, I don't want to import something just so it can appear in the docs.

[image: Screen capture]

### How do I make it work?

#### TDLR

Links within the same file work correctly. The problem is only with cross-file links, but there's no relevant reference to the subject in [VSCode's docs for the `@link` directive](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_57#_jsdoc-link-support).

I'm running:

- VSCode 1.58.2
- TypeScript 4.3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't this exactly how you'd expect it to work? If you add a link to a symbol, VS Code (or any IDE, really) needs to know what symbol exactly you mean.

If they'd just have to guess the symbol, not only would they have to go through **all** possible typed files, there would also be classes because e.g. 20 of your dependencies (or even 20 files within a single dependency) all create an `export interface Options` for example.

You *might* be able to get away with using `import('module').Export` as type.

---

Alternatively, you can use a [type-only import](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html), added in TypeScript 3.5:

```
import type { SomeType } from 'some-module';

// Works fine, since we're only using the type
type UsingTheType = Partial<SomeType>;

// Errors, because we didn't import the actual value
// (assuming it should be a value anyway, e.g. a class)
const someType = new SomeType();
```

If you look at the transpiled code, you'll notice that this doesn't actually result in an `import`/`require`. Type-only don't actually get imported at runtime, it only imports the types at compile-time.

*TypeScript should do the same trick if you use a regular import where values aren't used, but this is more explicit.*

Comment: You are probably right about the impossible guesswork. Expecting developers to add imports just for documentation however, definitely isn't how I would expect it to work. There should be a mechanism just for docs. The `import(...)` statement didn't work unfortunately. 

Comment: To be fair, usually when documentation is referencing a type, that type is already imported/declared locally (e.g. the documentation is for a function that has that type as argument or return value) one way or another. Mind that TypeScript also has type-only imports, e.g. `import type { Type } from 'module';` so that in the transpiled code, there isn't an actual import/require statement, i.e. it's purely for TS to import types.

Comment: Interesting thought about type-only imports.  Still not sure how I feel about this, but I think I'll add the import and silence my linter for now.

Comment: BTW, I think the type-only imports explanation should be part of the answer. Care to add it?

Comment: It might also be a hint to you: if the `ViewMode` is meant to be used for `OnObserverBaseDirective`, why not declare it in the same file there? Other modules importing `ViewMode` _probably_ also import `OnObserverBaseDirective`. _unless they import a derivate from another file, of course_

Comment: @ShyAgam you probably _would_ expect this behavior coming from languages that define everything symbol in a global namespace, like Java and PHP. For each of these a documentation system could determine a canonical location for a class. Javascript is different though.

Comment: A caveat to this approach, although I'm still using it - In VSCode, when you click on the link, it will redirect you to the line of the `import type` itself . But if you imported a class type for example and link to its properties (e.g. `import type { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';`, `/* {@link FormGroup.invalid invalid} */`) it works perfectly fine. This might be just a VSCode issue though.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer to this question is correct. You can always fix this by using a type-only import. **However**, sometimes the imported types are not used anywhere else in the file, so, assuming you're using ESLint, you'll probably get a `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` error/warning. I'm currently disabling the rule for such imports, which is far from ideal obviously. I think the ideal fix would be one that allows importing it within the TSDoc somehow.

Comment: That's a nice idea actually. Though importing inside the documentation will clutter the docs and lead import duplication. This should probably be a global directive set in the head of the file. Something like `//@ts-import { SomeFeature } from 'some-library'`.

Comment: I think the ideal fix would be that JSDoc should require a referenced type to be imported. Also the eslint rule should consider that reference as a use of the type, and if it is only referenced in JSDoc the rule should only trigger if the import is not type-only